# LT Spice and inductors parallel to AC voltage sources?

Tags: transformer, inductor, parallel, ltspice, voltage-source

[image]

This is a circuit I designed in LT Spice. There is no transformer component in LT Spice so I specified L1 and L2 as magnetically coupled with `K L1 L2 1` when I try to simulate I get an error that I have to add series resistance in order to run the simulation...

How do I avoid adding a useless resistor?

Comment: Just add a very small resistor (0.1 ohm). Any real transformer will have coil resistance, so it will only make your simulation more accurate (of course it would be even better to use a value based on the specs of the actual transformer you want to use).

Answer (score 1):

As The Photon points out, in anything realistic, there is a resistance (unless you are from the future and build everything with superconductors).

You try to put an ideal voltage source (btw. the ltspice setting is amplitude, and you probably want 120V rms) in parallel with an ideal inductor, both without any kind of resistance. What would probably be the current hat flows (and in turn, the voltage that comes out on the secondary)?

So infinite current is likely not wanted, thus any kind of resistance at that point is not at all useless. But maybe you were referring to a resistor component as being useless? Just right click the inductor (or better both of them) and set their series resistance value to something realistic (which depends on what kind of transformer you have in mind).